# AWS connection timed out when try to test SSH configuration

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh

Sup! I'm following this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html?icmpid=docs_acc_console_connect
The point is: I need to clone a repo from aws, already did all steps until 10, everything worked, I did the public SSH upload, it was accepted, generated a `SSH Key ID`, I've created a `config` file just like they said:

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  User APKASZLEXAMPLEHERE
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Did: `chmod 600 config` and then on step 10 when I should test if the SSH config it's working, I got this error from git bash console: `ssh: connect to host git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out`

I did a config on my firewall to "open" `port 22` inbound / outbound, disabled anti-virus but still getting this error... more detailed error:

```
 ssh -vvv git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Diego/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/Diego/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/c/Users/Diego/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/c/Users/Diego/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com [52.95.19.19] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 52.95.19.19 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Any idea about what can it be?

EDIT: I'm using windows 10

Comment: It looks like your network is blocking the connection. Can you try it from an alternative network? (eg home vs office vs tethered via your phone)

Comment: Yeah I tried using 4g and worked, also I did a call to my network provider and they said that will not unblock port22 cause of "security issues" god damn!

Answer (score 1):

Something wrong with your machine's network, check if your system logs in `/var/logs` alternatively you can use [Mac OSX Console App](https://support.apple.com/guide/console/welcome/mac)

The endpoint you are trying to connect is publicly accessible

```sh
$ nc -vz git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com 22
Connection to git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com port 22 [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
$ dig +short git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
52.95.19.19
```

Comment: I'm using windows 10, should this be the problem? :P

Comment: @DiegoBittencourt [How to Enable OpenSSH Server in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/enable-openssh-server-windows-10/) or use [wireshark](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wireshare/) for debugging the networking on your machine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem was my internet provider blocking port22, they said will not unblock cause "security issues"

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your network provider is blocking port 22.

As an alternative, you could **use HTTPS for git, rather than SSH**.

See: [Setup for HTTPS users using Git credentials - AWS CodeCommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html)